# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' after calling RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(...)

Tags: exception, bluetooth, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make a function to connect to a specific Bluetooth device.  I'm somewhat sure the DeviceInformation parameter is valid so the issue should be just contained to the function below.  A short period of time after the line `RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(...)` I will see `A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll` in the Output in Visual Studio and then see `The program '...' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).`.  Additionally, the exception is not being caught by `try{} catch(Exception e){}` so that might mean there is an issue elsewhere.

```
public async Task<bool> Connect(DeviceInformation deviceInformation)
{
    try
    {
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            rfcommService = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(deviceInformation.Id);
        });
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("edfdshjkfdsklfdjslkf");
        if (rfcommService == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(rfcommService.Device.ToString());

        await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(
                    rfcommService.ConnectionHostName,
                    rfcommService.ConnectionServiceName);

        dataReader = new DataReader(streamSocket.InputStream);
        dataWriter = new DataWriter(streamSocket.OutputStream);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception while connecting: " + e.Message);
        Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also have the following `Capabilities` in `Package.appxmanifest`:

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
<DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
  <m2:DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
    <m2:Device Id="any">
      <m2:Function Type="name:serialPort" />
    </m2:Device>
  </m2:DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: @user3956566 After having solved this issue, I guess the issue was that the method I was using was exclusive to WinRT desktop/tablet and does not work for phones.  The most likely reason for this will be, as you suggested, that a DLL is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the `DeviceInformation` of making a Bluetooth connection is for WinRT desktop/tablet and not phone.  The solution was to use a `PeerInformation` method.

The function now looks like the following:

```
public async Task<bool> Connect(PeerInformation peerInfo)
{
    streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
    try
    {
        await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(peerInfo.HostName, "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}");
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Writing can be done using `await streamSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(rawMessage.AsBuffer());`
.  Reading I still haven't figured out how to do yet but the issue I was having with this question was resolved by the above.